# Localhost to Live Server with forwading node js

Tags: node.js, localhost, webserver, portforwarding, forwarding

I have a localhost Server with node JS. But ı make my localhost make Live Server. But ı dont want use heroku etc. İn the arduino make localhost to Live Server with forwading. But how make this nodejs pc localhost.[forwading screen](https://ibb.co/Bn0tdbK)

What is the parameter.
My Server in the 192.168.1.31:8080

Comment: Take a look at https://ngrok.com/, maybe that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tunneling instead. go for ngrok or a few alternatives:

- Localtunnel
- Serveo
- Teleconsole
- Pagekite